# Waterproofing Issue In Yard

Tags: water, waterproofing, gutters, downspout

Having a problem in our yard that I am fairly certain is connected to a waterproofing project completed by the previous homeowner.

My layperson's understanding of the situation and work completed: the previous homeowner was experiencing water in the basement, so they had a company come in and cut out the floors at the edges of the foundation and install a system to redirect water. In addition, they installed pipes a few inches below the surface in the yard to redirect water from the downspouts away from the foundation. The downspouts feed directly into these pipes above ground, and the pipes seem to be running about 5-6 feet underground. I'm coming to that estimation because in the time we've been here I've noticed that two of the four downspouts seem to be creating very swampy pits about 5-6 feet away from them every time it rains, and it'll stay that way for days. These pits are only about 6-12 inches in diameter, and my guess is that the water is just pooling up rather than spreading through the soil which is clay-based in my area (SW Ohio).

I'm no expert on any of this, I just want a solution so I stop twisting my ankle in these surprise mud pits every time I cut the grass. I don't know if the way they completed the work was wrong, but it feels to me like some sort of exhaust should have been installed to allow the water to spread out when it reaches the ends of the pipes. I'm thinking that [this type of product](https://www.lowes.com/pd/NDS-5-3-4-in-W-x-3-in-dia-Pop-up-Emitter/1003180132?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-ggl-_-LIA_PLB_142_Pipe-Fittings-_-1003180132-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=CjwKCAjwlJimBhAsEiwA1hrp5hbKBYRx9eCRrGUDEAfkSZjLJgGD-TTdUczz7a5Y_KJXuECKqvW6zxoCiacQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) is what I need at the end of the pipes. Before I go start digging up my yard trying to install a couple of these, I was hoping to get some affirmation that I'm assessing the situation properly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Typical approach for slow-draining soils would be to install a **dry well** at the end of the pipes (at least the problem ones.)

That provides a larger area for water to infiltrate the soil, and also some storage for when the inflow exceeds the infiltration rate.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make underground extensions of these drains. You could cut out grass above like strips of sod, and then make trenches that you will fill with gravel or sand. People also add landscape fabric above these but below the topsoil to keep out the finer sediments that would clog the spaces between the grains of sand or bits of gravel.